# If $a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $c+d\equiv 0\pmod m$ then $ac+bd\equiv 0\pmod m$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

> If $a\equiv b\pmod m$ and $c+d\equiv 0\pmod m$ then $ac+bd\equiv 0\pmod m$.

The response, posted below is correct??

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @martini I posted this same question that you put the link, but you agaranto issues that are different from my friend!

Comment: @marcelolpjunior What friend? I do not quite get why you posted the same question twice.

Comment: @martini First call "friend" is something quite usual in Brazilian culture (I'm Brazilian).

Second, the questions, in my view, are not equal, because I posted this to know if this correct!

Comment: I missread your comment, I'm ok with you calling me fried, sry.

Answer (score 0):

Show:

> If $a\equiv b\pmod m\Longrightarrow m\mid a-b\Longrightarrow m\mid c(a-b)\Longrightarrow m\mid ac-bc\Longrightarrow \\ac-bc=mk$
>
> If $c+d\equiv 0\pmod m\Longrightarrow m\mid c+d\Longrightarrow m\mid b(c+d)\Longrightarrow m\mid bc+bd\\bc+bd=mj$

Adding, $ac-bc+bc+bd=mk+mj\\ac+bd=m(k+j)\\m\mid ac+bd\Longrightarrow ac+bd\equiv0\pmod m\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\Box$